# Fetch GET request hitting .catch() on anything but 200 response

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I have a redux store set up with actions to handle loading accounts. The action calls a service like so:

```
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`http://localapi.co.uk/api/account/load/${account_id}`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(account => {
            if(account.account.id) {
                localStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(account))
            }

            return account;
        })
        .catch(redirectToLogin)
```

Handle response is simply a function that checks the .status and .ok properties of the response and either displays an error or logs out if the response status is 401. This works perfectly fine for POST requests. When I hit my login route, any response hits the first .then(handleResponse) and deals with it.

When I send a GET request instead like above 404s, 401s, 500s.. etc all skip the .then(handleResponse) and instead jump to my catch. The problem that causes is that because catch doesn't actually give me a response object to work with I can't check the status - I want to do different things depending on whether the get was a 401 (I want to logout) or a 500 (I want to display a user error stating what went wrong) for example.

Is there a solution that will allow me to get a response or stop my GET requests hitting the .catch and instead hit the response handler I've written?

I'm using:

- a Laravel 5.7.20 back-end
- a React 16.7.0 front-end
- running local node server with npm start

Answer (score 0):

How about having a clean async/await function. Waiting till you JSON data becomes ready and then having the rest of your if logic or returning the account object from the function and moving the rest of the logic to the caller function. Something like this:

```
async myFunc({ account_id}) {
    const url = `http://localapi.co.uk/api/account/load/${account_id}`;
    const response = await fetch(url, { headers: headers: authHeader() });
    const account = await response.json();
    // return account (recommended);
    // Place your if logic here (not recommended because its not clean)
}
```